# Highlighting the selection in a RichEditBox

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro

I was wondering if anyone has used the RichEditBox in metro. I am looking to see how I can highlight the selection of an item based on a search.

I notice there is a document object exposed as a property but this seems to be read only and I can't seem to find how you would update the selection (I presumed it worked the same as a flow document in SL / WPF).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
 Windows.UI.Text.ITextSelection selection = richEditBox.Document.Selection;
 selection.StartPosition = 0;
 selection.EndPosition = n;
```

Comment: Ah! I missed the selection part! Cheers.